# Assign values with the := operator

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, performance, postgresql-performance

When I assign a variable with

```
result := title || '', by '' || author;
```

it is taking more time (approx. 15 sec) to run the function.
However, when I assign the variable with

```
result = title || '', by '' || author;
```

it takes only 133ms.

Why is it taking more time for the first scenario? And what is the reason behind this?

Full function is given below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.fn_get_res_no(reservation_no character varying)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$  

DECLARE  
    emd_status_firstcall varchar(2);  
    emd_status_secondcall varchar(2);
    emd_status      varchar(6);  
BEGIN  
    SELECT firstwscomplete, secondwscomplete
    INTO emd_status_firstcall, emd_status_secondcall
    FROM myschema.mytable
    WHERE respkgconfirmid = reservation_no;

    emd_status = emd_status_firstcall || ', ' || emd_status_secondcall;
    RETURN emd_status ;  

END;  
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: If you used dollar quoting (at least for the function body, like `CREATE FUNCTION bla() RETURNS void AS $body$ ... $body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;` then you wouldn't need doubled quotes in your code.  Just an idea.

Answer (score 7):

This question **concerns PL/pgSQL** exclusively, where **`:=`** is the assignment operator. It has no place in pure SQL.

Using `=` instead of `:=` in PL/pgSQL is an **undocumented legacy feature**, which should ***not*** be used.
[`:=` is the documented assignment operator in PL/pgSQL.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT).
[More details about that in this related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace).

***Update:*** Since Postgres 9.4 `=` is also documented as plpgsql assignement operator.

I have never seen `=` performing faster than `:=`. They should be identical. I fact, I tested your exact code in Postgres 9.1 and 9.2 and found **no difference** in performance whatsoever.
You may be mis-interpreting caching effects. Always run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` a couple of times to populate the cache and get comparable results.

*Finally*, you could replace your function with this much **simpler and faster** one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.fn_get_res_no(reservation_no varchar)
  RETURNS varchar AS
$BODY$  
BEGIN  
   RETURN (
      SELECT firstwscomplete || ', ' || secondwscomplete
      FROM   myschema.mytable
      WHERE  respkgconfirmid = reservation_no
      );
END  
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or even use a **plain SQL function**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.fn_get_res_no(reservation_no varchar)
  RETURNS varchar AS
$BODY$  
   SELECT firstwscomplete || ', ' || secondwscomplete
   FROM   myschema.mytable
   WHERE  respkgconfirmid = reservation_no);
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

#### Assignments in PL/pgSQL

It is comparatively expensive to make assignments in PL/pgSQL, which is a very simple Ada-like procedural language. Every assignment is executed with a (very simple) SELECT command, which is more expensive than in other fully fledged procedural languages.

PL/pgSQL excels as glue for SQL commands, when you need *some* procedural elements.

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thanks for the comments. However, I face this issue in the PostgreSQL 8.2. I wonder this issue has been fixed in the newer versions.

Comment: @kds: There is a *very* long list of things that have been fixed since Postgres 8.2. I strongly suggest you find a way to upgrade to a current version of Postgres. Consider the [versioning policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Next time also please remember to provide your version number with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know "=" is not an assignment operator in PL/pgSQL, it is a comparison operator. If this does not explain the issue then we'd best see the complete code.

Comment: Hi, I have added the full function in to the original question.